# minimalmodbus read multiple register on same device

Tags: python, modbus, minimalmodbus

Is there a way where I can read a set of register on a device with the python library  minimalmodbus? Or is it one by one I need to read_register like this?

```
instrument.read_register(0x0033,1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the minimalmodbus documentation for [`read_registers()`](https://minimalmodbus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/apiminimalmodbus.html#minimalmodbus.Instrument.read_registers). You shouldn't need to change the *functioncode* argument.

Assuming you want the first one hundred and twenty-five registers, starting at register zero:

```
registers = instrument.read_registers(0, 125)
```

If you wanted to print those registers:

```
for idx in range(len(registers)):
    print(f"Register {idx:3d} : {registers[idx]:5d} ({hex(registers[idx])})")
```

This will output something like:

```
Register   0 :     0 (0x0)
Register   1 :     1 (0x1)
Register   2 :     2 (0x2)
Register   3 :     3 (0x3)
Register   4 :     4 (0x4)
…
```

EDIT: Looking at page 9 of the [specification document](https://gavazzi.se/app/uploads/2020/11/em330_em340_et330_et340_cp.pdf), there are sixteen and thirty-two bit registers co-mingled. It will be easier to read them explicitly. Otherwise you'll need to shift and combine the two sixteen-bit registers, which is annoying and *minimalmodbus* has functions to make it easier and less error prone for you.

E.g.

```
# 0000h 2 V L1-N INT32 Value weight: Volt*10
# read_long(registeraddress: int, functioncode: int = 3, signed: bool = False, byteorder: int = 0) → int
L1_N_voltage = instrument.read_long(0, signed=True) / 10

# 0028h 2 W sys INT32 Value weight: Watt*10
sys_wattage = instrument.read_long(0x28, signed=True) / 10
```

Note that `read_long()` doesn't have `number_of_decimals` support, so you need to manually divide the reading by ten. For the current and power factor you'll need to divide by 1,000.

Comment: It 110% because I'm not a modbus expert... I have this device: https://gavazzi.se/app/uploads/2020/11/em330_em340_et330_et340_cp.pdf  (see page 9). 

I would like to read all values from register 0000h ->
```
registers = instrument.read_registers(0x0000,50)
```
But some how the registers in the documentation jumps. With code above I start at read 0000 and the next 50 register right? Is it possible to specify which registers, and make read for the specific registers?

Comment: The `read_registers()` function reads a sequential block of `UINT16` registers, so if you only want some specific registers, it'd be easier to use `read_register()`.